# check username and password vie ldap php

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to connect to my AD server and check if username and password is correct when I'm trying to do that, it always tells me:

> Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials

My code is:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($adserver,$adport);
$ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn,"$username","$password");
```

When I tried to set a username with and without domain name in this variations:
user@domain.co.il
domain\user
user

When I'm trying to bind anonymously, Its ok.
Do you have any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check username. It should be a properly formatted RDN/DN. Special characters must be escaped.

It would help if you post the value of `$username`.

Comment: can you give me an example?
I don't understand what you meant
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Active directory then you must set this options:

> ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
>
> ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

and use FULL DN (ex. uid=UserName,cn=Peoples,dc=example,dc=com) or short version (UserName@example.com) AD supports both types.